# Crash with SIGSEGV while using ffmpeg javacpp wrapper on android with segment output format

Tags: android, javacpp, android-ffmpeg

Applications constantly crashing with SIGSEGV if output format is 'segment'

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 17059
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in output file naming.
It should contain formatting directives like 'name_%03d.ts' so created files would be 'name_001.ts', 'name_002.ts'...